# Environment variable from docker-compose not being passed to container

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set an environment variable in my docker-compose file and it is not able to be accessed when running the container.

```
version: "2"
services:
  newman_runner:
    build:
      context: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/tree/develop/docker/images/alpine
      args:
        NEWMAN_VERSION: 4.6.0
    image: postman/newman:alpine
    environment:
      - FOO=BOO
    volumes:
      - ./postman:/etc/newman
    entrypoint: echo ${FOO}
#    command:
#      run /etc/newman/Google_Civic_Information_API.postman_collection.json
#      --env-var API_KEY=${API_KEY}
```

FOO comes back as Empty and I get the following WARNING after running `docker-compose.exe up` 
`WARNING: The FOO variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.`

I've tried to set FOO as both an array and a dictionary with similar effects.
`FOO: BOO` vs `- FOO=BOO`

Any ideas?

I'm on windows at the moment if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working was this:

```
version: "2"
services:
  newman_runner:
    build:
      context: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/tree/develop/docker/images/alpine
      args:
        NEWMAN_VERSION: 4.6.0
    image: postman/newman:alpine
    environment:
      - FOO
```

From there I can export FOO before running docker-compose

```sh
export FOO=BOO
docker-compose up
```